# tkinter - How to use file path entered into Entry widget as a variable?

Tags: python, tkinter, user-input, filepath

I have this GUI that generates an `Entry` widget and a `Button` widget. The user is supposed to enter a file path (example `"C:\Users\example\example"`) and that file path is used as the variable for the function `LoopAnalysis()`.

When I execute the code, the widgets work and I can copy and paste a file path into the `Entry` widget, but when I execute the command using the `Button` widget I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: ''
```

If the user inputs in the `Entry` window a file path, is there a specific syntax to use it as a variable? For example I know that for python in general if I manually define a variable as such.

```
Directory = r'C:\Users\example\example'
```

I need to add the `r` before the file path for python to recognize the entire line as a file path and not consider the special characters in the file path.

How do I do this for my function?

`Torque_Analysis` is already defined and works properly.

```
ws = Tk()
ws.title("Torque Analysis")
ws.geometry('1000x150')
ws['bg'] = 'black'

def LoopAnalysis(Directory):
    for filename in os.listdir(Directory):
        if filename.endswith(".csv"):
            Torque_Analysis(os.path.join(Directory, filename))
            plt.figure()
            plt.show(block = False)
        else: continue

UserEntry = Entry(ws, width = 150)
UserEntry.pack(pady=30)
Directory = UserEntry.get()

Button(ws,text="Click Here to Generate Curves", padx=10, pady=5, command=lambda: LoopAnalysis(Directory)).pack()

ws.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're calling `UserEntry.get()` about a millisecond after you create the entry widget, so it's going to return an empty string.

Comment: To avoid that, create a new function that calls `UserEntry.get()` and then calls `LoopAnalysis()`. Afterwards, make this new function the `command=` of the "Click Here" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in a comment to the question, you are calling `UserEntry.get()` once, as soon as the program starts. The entry box is blank then, so that blank string is read and stored in `Directory`, and the contents of `Directory` never changes again.

Instead, you need to call `UserEntry.get()` **every time the button is pressed**.

Try this:

```py
from tkinter import *
import os

ws = Tk()
ws.title("Torque Analysis")
ws.geometry('1000x150')
ws['bg'] = 'black'

def LoopAnalysis(Directory):
    for filename in os.listdir(Directory):
        if filename.endswith(".csv"):
            Torque_Analysis(os.path.join(Directory, filename))
            plt.figure()
            plt.show(block = False)
        else: continue

UserEntry = Entry(ws, width = 150)
UserEntry.pack(pady=30)
Button(ws,text="Click Here to Generate Curves", padx=10, pady=5, command=lambda: LoopAnalysis(UserEntry.get())).pack()

ws.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `get` method immediately after creating the entry widget, so it's going to return an empty string. In GUI programming, you need to get data from widgets at the point that you need the data, not before.

My recommendation is to *not* pass in the value to the function. Instead, have the function call `get`:

```
Button(..., command=LoopAnalysis)
...
def LoopAnalysis():
    Directory = UserEntry.get()
    ...
```